# transform string/char to uint8

Tags: string, matlab, ascii

Why does the expression:

```
test = cast(strtrim('3'), 'uint8')
```

produce 51?

This is also true for:

```
test = cast(strtrim('3'), 'int8')
```

Thanks.

Comment: because 51 is the ascii value for '3' ??

Comment: fair enough. makes kind of sense. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because 51 is the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the character `'3'`.

If you want to transform the string to numeric 3, you should use

```
uint8(str2double('3'))
```

Note that `str2double` will ignore trailing spaces, so that `strtrim` isn't necessary.

**EDIT**

When a string is used in an numeric operation, Matlab automatically converts it to its ASCII value. For example

```
>> '1'+1
ans =
    50
```

Comment: you can use that last property to easily convert string numbers back to numeric: `strnumbers='1234567890';` `strnumbers-'0'` returns the array `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0]`

Comment: You have to be careful, though, to have all strings, because `'0'-0` returns 48.

Comment: don't you mean `0-'0'` returns -48 ? True, but that as well applies to any function, eg: `str2double(0) returns `NaN` It's imo up to the developer/programmer to make a correct implementation and catch incorrect input when necessary.

Comment: @GuntherStruyf: I just wanted to point out that while your solution is quite clever, it can also be somewhat prone to errors or misunderstandings.

Answer (score 3):

Because 51 is the [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the character `'3'`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because '3' is seen as an ASCII character to matlab.  By casting as a signed or unsigned integer (8 bits in this case) you are asking Matlab to convert an ASCII '3' to a decimal number.  In this case the decimal number is 51.  If you want to look at more conversions [here](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html) is a basic document.